# Why does appending HTML via html() not work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, append, dynamic-data

I'm debuggin a site on `ie8` and cannot get dynamic content added via AJAX to display on the page.

The ajax call is done correctly, I can console.log/alert the returned HTML and there are no script errors popping up. Only a blank page with empty text node.

My script appending content looks like this:

```
// ajax content returned (HTML string)
var makeUp = data,
    target = $('.registryWrapper');

target.last()
    // css3 transition
    .addClass('fade out')
    // clear
    .html('')
    // add
    .html( makeUp )
    .append( someotherstuff )
    // Jquery Mobile enhancement
    .trigger('create')
    .removeClass('out')
    .addClass('in')
```

Any idea why this does not work in

Thanks!

Comment: do you still get blank if you just have target.last().html(makeUp)?

Comment: yup. blank page. Can it be the selector?

Comment: might be. I mocked up a simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jFdyH/), check the data is there and that your selector is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE8, .html()/.innerHTML will do nothing if the HTML coming in isn't *perfectly* formatted (against the DTD being used) - it doesn't tolerate any mistakes unlike when it's parsing normally.

If you substitute data with something very simple like `<p>Hello World!</p>` then you should find it works (if that doesn't then something else is wrong) - in which case you need to find what is wrong with the HTML being passed in.

Comment: ok. I see.... no-mercy-ie... should I just run the HTML snippet to a validator to see what may be missing?

Comment: Well the snippet alone wouldn't pass a validator, try sticking it in a minimal but compliant document.

Comment: yeah. I already found some bugs in the code. Fixing than posting back here if it works. IE sure is strict...